# PostgreSQL Avg Query

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to figure out how to write a query that will give me the average of 3 different columns so I can populate them in a graph. What I have is a program that adds a record to a table every 5 min with a current water level from an ultrasonic sensor. So for the current sensor I'm working on there is 1000 records. What I want to do is show 10 averages in the graph, so each average is going to be 100 records averaged together. The 3 averaged columns needed for the graph is depth, date, time. The table is named data_tank. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Example of table]
Lets forget about the 3 columns, All I need at the moment is to get the average of the tank_level. So in the picture there are 20 rows, The max data points that I want to display is 10 so every 2 rows would need to be averaged together.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. You say you want to show 10 averages in the graph, but you need 3 columns to be averaged. It sounds more like you want _one_ column averaged over *date* plus *time*.

Comment: Post sample data and expected output

Comment: I appreciate y'all responding. I have updated the post with a link to a snapshot of the table in question. 20 rows are being displayed and the graph I'm doing will support 10 data points. So every 2 rows would need to be averaged for the tank_level in this example. Please disregard the 3 columns comment, sorry it was confusing. For the actual project though I'm looking at thousands of records that will need to be split into 10 averages of equal row counts. Thank y'all again.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t (id, tank_level, job_id) as (values (1,1,26),(2,2,26),(3,3,26),(4,4,26))
select avg(tank_level)
from (
    select row_number() over (order by id) as rn, tank_level
    from t
    where job_id = 26
) s
group by (rn + 1)/ 2
;
        avg         
--------------------
 1.5000000000000000
 3.5000000000000000
```

Comment: I tried adapting what you posted to what Im trying to accomplish.  Select avg(tank_level) FROM data_tanksensor WHERE job_id = 26 group by (id + ((Select count(*) FROM data_tanksensor WHERE job_id = 26) / 10)) But the result was well over 10 records. The total "count" is 1002. Any ideas why its displaying more than 10 records

Comment: @Derek Edited. Do not sum anything to the row number.

Comment: I guess where I'm getting lost is say we add 2 more data points to your example but still only want 2 averaged numbers how do you change the group by to adjust for this? The amount of rows I'm averaging is never static. I tried doing  - with t (id, tank_level, job_id) as (values (1,5,26),(2,7,26),(3,3,26),(4,4,26),(5,5,26),(6,6,26))  and changed the group by to  - group by (rn + 1)/ 3 and got 3 records

Comment: Well I figured out that one change the group by to  - group by (rn + 2)/ 3  and it comes out correct, but still how can I adjust it for record counts that are not known until the user tries to create a history graph. I assume I have to use count to get the current amount of rows? And the "with" statement would not be used since its coming directly from a table there is no need to create another right?

Comment: `select avg(tank_level)
from (
    select row_number() over (order by id) as rn, tank_level
    from data_tanksensor
    where job_id = 26
) s
group by (rn + ((Select count(*)/10 From data_tanksensor where job_id = 26) - 1))/ (Select count(*)/10 From data_tanksensor where job_id = 26)
;` Does this look correct to you? I am getting 11 records the total record count is 1002 for this job_id before selecting averages.

Comment: Also what does the `s` stand for in `s group by ...` Thank you